# Mysql server won't start - no logs

Tags: mysql

After a restart, mysql won't start. `sudo service mysql start` gives `start: Job failed to start` and the logs are empty, so I have no idea where to start. I'm pretty sure permissions problems are taken care of.

Edit:
All disks have at least 1G of space and `sh -x /etc/init.d/mysql start` gives me:

```
+ set -e
+ basename /etc/init.d/mysql
+ INITSCRIPT=mysql
+ JOB=mysql
+ [ mysql = upstart-job ]
+ [ -z start ]
+ COMMAND=start
+ shift
+ [ -z  ]
+ ECHO=echo
+ echo Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
+ echo utility, e.g. service mysql start
utility, e.g. service mysql start
+ echo

+ echo Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
+ echo Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
+ grep -q  start/
+ status mysql
+ [ -z  ]
+ [ start = stop ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ start mysql
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.105" (uid=1000 pid=3208 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` nothing in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/mysqld` ?

Comment: Do you have any full disks? If the log disk is full, it can't write a log.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution for it? None of the answers here fixed the problem. :/

Comment: I believe I had to reinstall (purge with a manual backup of /var/lib/mysql)

Answer (score 4):

This message comes from the service script, not from mysql. So you have to look at the script and figure where/why it fails.

Do that by calling `sh -x /etc/init.d/mysqld start`.

note: on some questions, like this one, I don't see any "add comment". I only have the option to add an answer. How can I just add a comment ?

Comment: Gregory, I believe you don't have the ability yet.  You get more access as you build reputation.  It's probably to prevent automated spam comments on spam posts by newly created users.

Comment: Well this is an answer and not a comment. To outline it a bit further I will edit Gergorys answer a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, for me the reason was, that the `my.cnf` file has been moved from `/etc/my.cnf` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, but there still was a "dead" symlink pointing to `/etc/my.cnf`.

Check if `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is a symlink:

```
user@machine:~ $ ls -l /etc/mysql/my.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 11  2011 /etc/mysql/my.cnf -> ../my.cnf
```

If it is a symlink, check if the target file exists. If not, remove the symlink and create `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-new` or something like that... if you have it.

```
sudo unlink /etc/mysql/my.cnf
sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-new /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

P.S: If the symlink's target is existing, you might want to check `dmesg | grep cnf` for apparmor error messages.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can occur if the pid file still exists, such as after a crash. Check for that and delete it if it does exist.

The pid file location defaults to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` but a different location may be set in the config file.

Comment: This can be cleared by stopping mysql (even if it isn't running), and starting it up again.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. The filesystem was 100% full

Confirm with: `df -h /`